# Python - Why does the second for loop start from the second row

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have these two for loops, the first one loops through a csv reader and the second loops through a csv DictReader. When results are printed I see that the first one is starting from the first row and the second is starting from the second row which I don't know why as it's a new loop. When I comment out the first one, the second one starts normally from the first row. Here is the code:

```
csvFile = open('contactscsv.csv', 'r')
headerReaderReader = csv.reader(csvFile)
headerReaderDict = csv.DictReader(csvFile)

for row in headerReaderReader:
    print(row)
    break

for row in headerReaderDict:
    print(row)
    break
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reading from the same open file object, so your first `headerReaderReader = csv.reader(csvFile)` is starting from the first unread row and `headerReaderDict = csv.DictReader(csvFile)` is starting from the next unread row. If you reordered them to be

```
headerReaderDict = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
headerReaderReader = csv.reader(csvFile)

for row in headerReaderReader:
    print(row)
    break

for row in headerReaderDict:
    print(row)
    break
```

then `headerReaderReader` will start from the second row and `headerReaderDict` will start from the first.

If you really need to open 2 copies of the same file, you will need to maintain 2 different objects to avoid sharing the same pointer:

```
with open('contactscsv.csv', 'r') as csv1, open('contactscsv.csv', 'r') as csv2:
    headerReaderReader = csv.reader(csv1)
    headerReaderDict = csv.DictReader(csv2)
```

Comment: OK reordering the reader and dictReader did not do any difference, the difference comes when you reorder the for loops. I never faced this in Java or C. I'm new to Python so there is certainly something I don't understand about for loops or iteration in python, can you tell me what topic to read about in order to understand this.